# Spring Boot can not find AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

When I build my jar, I get `ClassNotFoundException` for `AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer`.
This class is not in Spring libraries built by Gradle and also the class is not necessary for running in IDE. Is it possible to disable searching for this class? Or do you have some other solution?

EXCEPTION:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:438)
        ... 10 more
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
}
```

Comment: "build my jar" `jar` or `bootJar` ??? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `spring-boot-starter` dependency which includes `spring-boot-starter-logging` which has the class you are missing